# Greasemonkey script that refreshes page

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

So, at my school theyy have this service which tells you that "your request has been coached", so I have made a GM script to automatically refresh the page and continue on to the content you wanted. To avoid the hassle of pressing F5 I made this:

```
function main(doc) {
if (document.title == "REQUEST COACHED") {
window.location.reload();}
if (document.title == "REQUEST BLOCKED") {
 I GOT STUCK HERE
}
}
main(document);
```

Will it work?
And also, if the page is blocked, you will receive a page that says you have been blocked with the title "REQUEST BLOCKED", what I don't know how to do is, append .nyud.net to the url of the site. So instead of:

stackoverflow.com/questions

I get:

stackoverflow.com.nyud.net/questions

so I can continue viewing the content I wanted to (the school blocks all forums and chatroom sites, which often are useful for information, especially the physicsforums.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
window.location = window.location.replace(/(.+)\/(.*)/, '$1.nyud.net/$2')
```

?